# Using 'runas' command and check which USER/DOMAIN the current session is on

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, runas

I often run `cmd` shell using `runas` with multiple domain accounts, how could I get the domain name from the shell that was running under a different domain account?

Example:

```
C:\>echo %userdomain%
DOMAIN1
C:\>runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN2\USER cmd
Enter the password for DOMAIN2\USER:
Attempting to start cmd as user "DOMAIN2\USER" ...
```

Now on the new shell which is running as `DOMAIN2\USER` still gives me the `%userdomain%` output as `DOMAIN1`. Is there a way I could get the domain of `runas` account?

Comment: What does the command "WhoAmI" returns in your case?

Comment: I get the same `DOMAIN1\USER` in session 1 and in the `runas` session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of **RunAs** when used with the */netonly* parameter.

Using */netonly* allows you to run your command/application/shell with your user (DOMAIN1\USER), while authenticating over the network with another user (DOMAIN2\USER).

From Microsoft Documentation:

**/netonly** Indicates that the user information specified is for remote access only. This parameter cannot be used with the /profile parameter.

You can however open the new cmd.exe prompt with a command that will set a variable you can then use... for example:

```
runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN2\USER "cmd /K SET NETONLYUSER=DOMAIN2\USER"
```

So you can access this variable in the new cmd.exe with *%NETONLYUSER%*

Comment: Maybe to clarify. It changes the identity of any remote call, but everything you do locally remains under the original identity.